# When indexing documents in Solr 7, I am recieving an response that I don't understand

Tags: indexing, solr

I am indexing a series of documents and am occasionally receiving the following error. I have searched around and am not able to understand what the following error means:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">400</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">Unexpected EOF in CDATA section
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,8191]</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Check the server log for your Solr instance (and if you have multiple instances, check the whole cluster) - it should contain an actual stacktrace.

Comment: EOF (End Of File) means your POST was truncated, I don't think the fact that it's truncated in a CDATA section is relevant though, and the *col 8191* might rather indicate a limitation in size (request data size limited ? server side or client side ?), but I could be wrong. How do you post your data ?

Comment: @EricLavault, I am posting an xml file via curl. curl http://localhost:9999/solr/documents/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary file.xml.